# Updating a parent collection based on a child binding in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

I have a collection of items, which I have bound to an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
                        </ToggleButton>
```

I then have a second items collection which, in my view model, is based on a query, dependant on the above collection.

So, my requirement is to filter a list of products, based on the above category.  The problem that I have is that the above binding is to a ProductCategory; so, while the set fires correctly for the 'IsSelected' property on ProductCategory, it doesn't notify that the 'ProductCategories' has changed.

ProductCategories is defined as:

```
public class ProductCategories : ObservableCollection<ProductCategory>
```

My first thought was that I could achieve this by using a DataTrigger; however, these don't seem to be available since WinRT.  I could also use some kind of message notification for this, but I feel like this is something that should be achievable directly from the XAML binding.

So, my question is, is it possible to raise a notify that the parent class has changed, when the child class is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTriggers are available in UWP using this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed

Here the link to the wiki https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior

Using this, you can invoke Command using DataTrigger binded to IsSelected.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to filter one collection (Products?) by the selected item from another collection (ProductCategories)?

If so, you seem to be over thinking this slightly. Remove any 'IsSelected' concept from your ProductCategory class as this is display related and does not belong in your model. Then change the ProductCategories ItemsControl to a ListBox and bind the LsitBox.SelectedItem to a 'SelectedProductCategory' property in your view model as `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. When the user selects an item in the ListBox, the 'SelectedProductCategory' setter will be called, at which point you can filter your second collection (remembering to call PropertyChanged if the collection doesn't support change notification).

Hope it helps.